# Micropython urllib

Tags: json, urllib, esp8266, micropython

I am trying to read json data by url on ESP8266 board.

```
from urllib.urequest import urlopen
import json
url ="https://dashboard.elering.ee/api/nps/price?start=2021-12-01T21%3A00%3A00.000Z&end=2021-12-02T20%3A00%3A00.000Z"
response = urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
print(data)
```

I get error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/lib/urllib/urequest.py", line 30, in urlopen
OSError: -40
```

However the code works fine with different URL

```
url="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/1"
```

Both URL-s are valid.

Comment: did you try creating a sample json like the one in albums/1 but with a structure similar to the one in the failing scenario - in other words, with a nested obj containing arrays of objects ? The error seems to be triggered by functionality not used when parsing albums/1 hence no errors. My guess...

Comment: Did you consider that the response might not fit into memory? The response of the 2nd URL is significantly smaller.

Comment: The first URL is HTTP**S** and the second one isn't. And line 30 is `ctx = ussl.SSLContext()` in the latest code. Seems it doesn't work with encrypted connections for some reason.

Comment: Its SSL related error- unsupported ciphers. read more here: https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib/issues/400